# Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource even though I have owner role on the Azure Key Vault and also subscription

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, role-based-access-control

```
**CODE**: Forbidden

**MESSAGE**
The operation is not allowed by RBAC. If role assignments were recently changed, please wait several minutes 
for role assignments to become effective.
**RAW ERROR**
Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource. If role assignments, deny assignments or 
role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time. 
Caller: appid=guidId;oid=guidid;iss=https://sts.windows.net/guidid/ Action: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/setSecret/action' 
**Resource**: '/subscriptions/subs_id/resourcegroups/networkwatcherrg/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/vickyskeyvault001/secrets/productiondbpassword' 
Assignment: (not found) DenyAssignmentId: null DecisionReason: null Vault: vickyskeyvault001;location=centralindia
```

Even though I have owner role on keyvault and also subscription:

[image]

It's been more than 10 minutes, the message didn't go:

[image]

**Message**:
`The operation is not allowed by RBAC. If role assignments were recently changed, please wait several minutes for role assignments to become effective.`

Comment: It takes sometime for the role to reflect. Have you given it a retry after sometime?

Comment: Yes, it's been more than 5 minutes. I'm getting the same message still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if the user or service principal **does not** have key vault related roles assigned, while working with Azure key vaults.

When I tried to create keys in Azure Key Vault with <kbd>Owner</kbd>  role, I too got **same error** like this:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to assign key vault related roles like   <kbd>**Key Vault Administrator**</kbd> to the user or service principal:

[image]

Once this role is assigned, the warning message gone and I'm able to create **keys** successfully in key vault like this:

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the resolution, it helped me and my team as well